# how to install pip3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to install pip on Ubuntu by :

```
apt-get update
```

I received this message.
I would appreciate it if you help me through this:

```
could not open lock file /var/lib/lock-fronted - open(13:permission denied)
```

Comment: use `sudo apt update`, if issue still presists reboot your system and try the same command `sudo apt update`

Comment: you should avoid running multiple instances of apt commands simultaneously, such as `apt-get install`, `apt-get update`, or `apt-get upgrade`, as this can lead to conflicts and errors

Comment: When you run an `apt` command, it acquires a lock on the package management system to prevent other processes from making changes at the same time. If you try to run another `apt` command while an existing command is still executing, the second command will fail to acquire the lock and may display such error message

Comment: Use correct upper case letters please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the app installer from Ubuntu. However if you want to do it with terminal walk this steps:

Disable the automatic updater then reboot.

Close the updater if it still running.

Sometimes it start ~20s after the system start so wait a bit, then close it.

Try `sudo apt update` again.

Comment: where should I disable the automatic updater?

Comment: in the update manager click in edit>preferences then disable automatic update schedule.

You can find it in the app launcher of ubuntu or typing update-manager on the terminal.